# Как автоматически уменьшать размер текста в UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

У объекта `UITextField` есть свойства `Min Font Size` и `Adjust to Fit`, которые отвечают за уменьшение текста при вводе символов.

Каким образом сделать уменьшение текста в `UITextView`?

Ну или возможно сделать перенос строк в `UITextField`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Объявить `UITextField` в `properties`
2. При инициализации поставить параметр `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`
3. Подписаться на делегат [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), на редактирование `textFieldDidBeginEditing`
4. При изменении текста ресайзить его в методе делегата

   // определяем новый размер текста

   ```
   CGRect fieldSize = [field.text
                      boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight)
                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : field.font}
                      context:nil];

   // обновляем фрейм
   field.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, CGRectGetWidth(fieldSize), CGRectGetHeight(fieldSize));
   ```

Comment: сделал все также как и вы описали, при старте редактирования поля оно пропадает. В чем может быть проблема?
https://gist.github.com/10524065

Comment: @Serge Obrazcov думаю проблема тут, избегайте констант и магических чисел при задании фреймов

textField.frame = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(fieldSize), CGRectGetHeight(fieldSize));

Comment: @Алексей Алыбин, теперь высота меняется но текст не переносится по строкам

Comment: numberOfLines = 0 поставь при инициализаци, но всё это должно проще работать, возможно не в ту сторону копаем